# My GPU cycles viewport render is completely grey

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, gpu

I’m very new to blender and i just got a new GPU (AMD Radeon RX 580) to improve rendering, EEVEE and everything else works totally fine but if i try to use Cycles everything in the view turns completely grey, if i instead use my CPU for cycles it renders normally.

[image]

GPU render (light changes nothing)

I tried looking online for what the problem might be but i couldn’t find anything matching my problem, and the few similar ones i found didn’t give me any useful solution for this.
Has anyone had a similar problem? if yes how did you solve it? (My OS is Windows 10, I have all the drivers installed)